# Bash: for every line in file, run command, and write output

Tags: bash, scripting

How can I read in every line from a file, run some php manipulation, and save the output?  I have:

```
cat weblinks | php /my/php/file.php -a -r | grep -v0 > output
```

The problem is that `output` only has the output from the last line in `weblinks`!  How can I get results for every line in `weblinks` and not just the last?

Comment: Why do you believe that it should contain any more than that?

Comment: `cat weblinks | php /my/php/file.php -a -r | grep -v0 >> output` won't wokr?

Comment: what is `file.php`? what command-line arguments does it accept?

Comment: Does `file.php` output more than one line? Does the `grep` only match the last line? You don't give enough information to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might try piping into xargs and appending to the file:

`cat weblinks | xargs php /my/php/file.php -ar | grep -v0 >> output`

Comment: It says `xargs: php: exited with status 255; aborting` is that expected behavior?

Comment: No, that isn't the expected behavior. :) If you can provide more detail about the contents of `weblinks` and what manipulation you're performing, I give better advice.

Comment: `>>` appends to the file. It mixes output from multiple runs. And it has no effect on whether only results corresponding to the last line in the input (`weblinks`) are saved. Unless `file.php` accepts multiple command-line arguments (`xargs` passes each line from `weblinks` as an argument); it fails.